# Styles inside of a Vue app not rendering correctly

Tags: css, vue.js

I recently created my first Vue web app. During the creation of this I noticed that my delete buttons weren't rendering correctly. I tried a few things with the styling of it but it seems like nothing I've tried will work. Any thoughts?

Github Repo: https://github.com/Ocheezyy/VueTodo

Live site: https://vuetodo-ocheezyy.netlify.app/#/

Vue code:

```
<template>
    <div class="todo-item" v-bind:class="{'is-complete':todo.completed}">
        <input class="check" type="checkbox" v-on:change="markComplete">
        <p>{{todo.title}}</p>
        <button @click="$emit('del-todo', todo.id)" class="del">x</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "TodoItem",
    props: ["todo"],
    methods: {
        markComplete() {
            this.todo.completed = !this.todo.completed;
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
    .todo-item {
        background: #f4f4f4;
        padding: 10px;
        border-bottom: 1px #ccc dotted;
        
    }

    .todo-item p{
        flex-grow:1;
    }

    .is-complete {
        text-decoration: line-through;
    }

    .del {
        background: #ff0000;
        color: #fff;
        border: none;
        padding: 5px 9px; 
        border-radius: 50%;
        cursor: pointer;
        float: right;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Could you please include the relevant code in your question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Phil I have added relevant code if anyone were to look at this thread in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use flexBox instead of floating the elements.

Try:

```
.todo-item {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
    display: flex;
}
```

remove `floats` from `.check` and `.del`

then add:

```
.todo-item p{
 flex-grow:1;
}
```